# Unreal Engine 4 Android Building Error

Tags: android, unreal-4

Android Launch error
My sdk settings:

[image]

[image]

```
LogPlayLevel: UnrealBuildTool: Preparing native code for debugging...
!LogPlayLevel: UnrealBuildTool: UnrealBuildTool Exception: ERROR: D:/Program Files/NDK/NVPACK/android-ndk-r12b/ndk-build.cmd failed with args APP_ABI="arm64-v8a " NDK_DEBUG=1
LogPlayLevel: CommandUtils.Run: Run: Took 36,7394016s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
LogPlayLevel: BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults:Error: Error Launch failed! Unknown Error
```

Comment: Is there a way to have more a verbose error out put?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I 'am trying to deploy my game on my tablet android 5.1 (API 22) so this is what I did : 
 - Project Settings > Android > 
 - check Support arm64 [aka arm64-v8a]

[image]

just that and then I had the Gradle problem I just unchecked the "Enable Gradle Instead of Ant"

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it depends on the sequence of the installation. In my case I have to install the NDK first and Unreal later.

The other thing you can do is to check your environment variables if the NDK variables are there or not. If present then clear all location values from SDK config and try to build again that should work.

Comment: i  clear all locations values from SDK config, but i still get this problem(

Comment: i tried to move NVPACK to C disk, tried launch editor as administranor , change paths in windows Environment Variables, but then I get this error!

Comment: What I meant was to do a clean installation... in my experience I tried to avoid the clean install too but that didnt work.